# How to go to a frame label after end of the flv video?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have imported video FLV Player(with no skin) in layer(flv1)
The flv Player instance name is "myflvplayer1"

Actions: Frame 1

```
myflvplayer1.stop();
myflvplayer1.visible=false;
myflvplayer1.fullScreenTakeOver=false;

try{
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}catch(e)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Till frame 142 there's animation playing, after that:

```
stop();
myflvplayer1.visible=true;
myflvplayer1.play();
```

(so here video start to play in full screen)
Now when this video finishes I want it to Jump to frame label "main"
Where I have put many navigation buttons (My main menu page)

So any help will be very great.!
This is DVD based presentation, so everything is being loaded Local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Abhishek Try this

as2

```
myflvplayback.addEventListener("complete",completefunc);
function completefunc(e)
{
    trace("completed");
    //do any thing you want at complete like gotoAndPlay /gotoAndStop ("Framelabel");
}
```

as3

```
myflvplayback.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completefunc);
function completefunc(e)
{
    trace("completed");
    //do any thing you want at complete like gotoAndPlay /gotoAndStop ("Framelabel");
}
```

give me a plus if like my answer.

Comment: **Thanks it worked!**

I just have to change "myflvplayback" to "myflvplayer1"
I couldn't give + because I am new here..

Answer (score 0):

`gotoAndPlay("main");`
If this doesn't work, use ' instead of " (not sure which one it is).

Not that hard to find btw. If you google this, you'll find it easily.

Comment: I don't know what time it is in your country.. but i found it at the the first try, one of the first results.